# forms submits multiple times though its prevented

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my script:

```
$("#search").on("click", function () {
  $("#search_tutor").submit(function () {
      data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "fetch_tutor.php",
          data: data,
          success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
          }
      });
      return false;
  });
});
```

Problem I'm facing is:

When I click `$("#search")` for the first time, `alert(data);` appears once. When I click `$("#search")` for the second time `alert(data);` appears twice. So do it happens when I click the following times. Depending to how many times I click on the `$("#search")` that many times `alert(data);` appears. From my understanding this shows that `$("#search_tutor")` is submitted multiple time.Its because I used `return false` after the ajax function to prevent page from reloading.But when I refresh the page `alert(data);` appears only once.
I tried:

1) removing the `return false` but it reloads the page which I don't want to happen as its not appending the result I received form ajax call to a specified div.

This doesn't make any change.
2)

```
 $("#search_tutor").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
```

This doesn't allow anything to take place after the button is clicked.
3)

```
$("#search").on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

The only solution I can think of is, to reload the page after every ajax call but need to append result of ajax into the specified div. But how do I do that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are registerig the submit handler inside a click handler, so in each click of the button  a  new submit handler is registered.

So the second click of the button will call the submit handler twice, sending the ajax request twice.

There is no need to use the click handler, just use the submit event

```
$("#search_tutor").submit(function() {

  var data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "fetch_tutor.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: OP may want to submit the form on some other action, I guess. I don't find any need to use `submit` event.

Comment: @Arun P Johny, thanks for the explanation. However I need to submit the form on click event. Therefore I don't find any other way to submit it unless #search is clicked.

Comment: just understood what you mean by no need click event handler. As long as the #search is of input[type=submit], can submit it when the button is hit. NO need to call extra click event. Thanks a lot